# Is returning only IDs for a JSON API collection allowed?

Tags: json, rest, json-api

So let's say I have a resources called `articles`. These have a numeric id and you can access them under something such as:

`GET /articles/1` for a specific article.

And let's say that returns something like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "JSON:API paints my bikeshed!",
      "body": "A bunch of text here"
    }
  }
}
```

Now my question is how to handle a request to `GET /articles`. I.e. how to deal with the request to the collection.

You see, accessing the body of the article is slow and painful. The last thing I want this REST API to do is actually try to get all that information. Yet as far as I can tell the JSON API schema seems to assume that you can always return full resources.

Is there any "allowed" way to return just the IDs (or partial attributes, like "title") under JSON API while actively not providing the ability to get the full resource?

Something like:

`GET /articles` returning:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "article_snubs",
      "id": 1,
      "attributes": {
         "title": "JSON:API paints my bikeshed!"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "article_snubs",
      "id": 2,
      "attributes": {
         "title": "Some second thing here"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Maybe with links to the full articles?

Basically, is this at all possible while following JSON API or a REST standard? Because there is absolutely no way that `GET /articles` is ever going to be returning full resources due to the associate cost of getting the data, which I do not think is a rare situation to be in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand the JSON API specification there is no requirement that an API must return all fields (attributes and relationships) of a resource by default. The only *MUST* statement regarding fields inclusion that I'm aware of is related to *Sparse Fieldsets* (`fields` query param):

> **Sparse Fieldsets**
>
> [...]
>
> If a client requests a restricted set of fields for a given resource type, an endpoint MUST NOT include additional fields in resource objects of that type in its response.
>
> https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-sparse-fieldsets

Even so this is not forbidden by spec I would not recommend that approach. Returning only a subset of fields makes consuming your API much harder as you have to consult the documentation in order to get a list of all supported fields. It's much more within the meaning of the spec to let the client decide which information (and [related resources](https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes)) should be included.

Comment: So this spec provides no default way to deal with costly retrievals of data? It always assumes the client has full power with no restrictions (like rate limits?). That's unfortunate. I simply cannot allow a request for the collection to provide full information for every object (even with pagination). And I agree that not returning full data is unclear without a proper way to deal with it.... I see this as a shortfall of the spec honestly. It's not uncommon for some data retrievals to be costly.

Comment: I guess I could create some "key" resource, and back it with the larger and bulkier related resources, but it just feels kind of messy.

Comment: You could provide a link to fetch the full resource as [`links.self`](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-links), you could provide additional meta information (e.g. a list of all existing fields) using [`meta` key](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-meta). The spec does not force you to always return all available fields. It does not even force you to return all available fields if client explicitly asked you to do. I would just recommend that you have very good reasons to do so as that would make life of your consumers much harder.

Answer (score 0):

The "attributes" object of a JSON-API doc does not need to be a complete representation:

> attributes: an attributes object representing *some* of the resource’s data.

You can provide a "self" link to get the full representation, or perhaps even a "body" link to get just the body:

> links: a links object containing links related to the resource.

E.g.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "articles_snubs",
      "id": "1",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "JSON API paints my bikeshed!"
      },
      "links": {
        "self": "/articles/1",
        "body": "/articles/1/body"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "type": "article_snubs",
      "id": "2",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Some second thing here"
      },
      "links": {
        "self": "/articles/2",
        "body": "/articles/2/body"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is not valid according to [JSON:API specification](https://jsonapi.org/format/).

Comment: Edited the example to be json-api compliant.